# How to move up/down a single accordion html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've got multiple accordions from Bootstrap 4. I want a single accordion to move up/down when I click its corresponding arrow. How do I go about this in JS or jQuery?

[image]

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h3 class="mb-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#testchild" href="#section-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Disco Full Overview
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-tooltip-edit"></i> Edit
                </button>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm pull-right">
                <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down" style="font-size: 21px"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm pull-right">
                <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-up" style="font-size: 21px"></i>
            </button>

        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="section-1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="card-block">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h3 class="mb-0">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#testchild" href="#section-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Disco Test
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-tooltip-edit"></i> Edit
                </button>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm pull-right">
                <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down" style="font-size: 21px"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm pull-right">
                <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-up" style="font-size: 21px"></i>
            </button>

        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="section-2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="card-block">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've already set up the arrow keys but I don't know how to do this.

Edit.
I've found about insertafter and insertbefore but I don't know how parent and child works. Because the up/down button is child to the other elements and I don't know how to address the entire accordion.

Comment: you can use `sortable` with `accordion`. But it makes your accordion drag and drop. [Look Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9h99pd5t/)

Comment: @Regolith yeah I've found that. but I have to do it with arrows